# Looping through pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm manually looking for all values in my df columns like this (to search for weird entries):

```
df['sex'].value_counts(), df['famsize'].value_counts(), df['Pstatus'].value_counts(), df['traveltime'].value_counts()...
```

then i get:

```
(F    591
 M    453
 Name: sex, dtype: int64,
 GT3    738
 LE3    306
 Name: famsize, dtype: int64,
 T    923
 A    121
 Name: Pstatus, dtype: int64,
 1    623
 2    320
 3     77
 4     24
(...)
```

But there are so many columns, so I tried to loop through it :

```
for v in df.columns:
    df[v].value_counts()
```

but nothing is returned, I also tried:

```
for v in df.columns:
    df[v].value_counts().apply(display)
```

and:

```
for v in df.columns:
    df[v].value_counts().apply(print)
```

but it returns a long list of numbers without the indexes/labels.

Is there another way to automatically look through my dfs values? Maybe still using loop for.

Comment: Did you try `print(df[v].value_counts())`?

Comment: It *does* return something, you just aren't doing anything with what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do:

```py
for v in df.columns:
    print(df[v].value_counts())
```